# Is there a condition for the following consequence?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two real vectors $v = (v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ and $u = (u_1,\ldots,u_n)$.
I know that the dot product of $u$ and $v$ is larger than $\delta > 0$:

$\langle u,v \rangle \ge \delta$.

What would be an interesting condition on $u$, $v$ or both such that I have $u_i v_i \ge f(\delta)$ for each coordinate $i$ with some real function $f()$?

For example, one condition that I thought about is that for any $j \le n$ we have:

$\sum_{i \neq j} u_i v_i \le \delta/2$

and then we can get that $u_i v_i \ge \delta/2$ for every $i$ using triangle inequality.

You can assume that $||u|| = 1$ and that $||v||$ is bounded by some $M$ (L-2 norms here).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: btw, your example is not true. If for any $j \leq n$ you have $\sum_{i\neq j} u_i v_i \leq \delta / 2$, then summing over $j$ you get $$\sum_j \sum_{i\neq j} u_iv_i = (n-1) \langle u,v\rangle \leq n\delta / 2$$ or equivalently $\langle u,v\rangle \leq n\delta / (2n - 2) < \delta$ if $n > 2$, which contradicts your assumption that the inner product is bounded below by $\delta$.

Answer (score 2):

If I read you correctly, what you are trying to do is not possible in general. But it may be doable if you give more precisely what $u$'s and $v$'s are allowed, as well as what the desired function $f$ is.

Case in point: let $u$ be the unit vector in the $x_1$ direction. Then $u_iv_i = 0$ for any $i\neq 1$. So for any $f(\delta)$ such that $f$ sends positive numbers to strictly positive numbers, the inequality you are looking for is impossible.

In general, it is not generally very doable to try to estimate *coordinate dependent* quantities (individual $u_iv_i$) by manifestly *coordinate independent* ones (the dot product). At best you can expect only something trivial in the general case.